# Fading in elements are shifting and adjusting

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, fadein

I've made a simple website where user can type a word and the result is fading in into appropriate `div` . The problem is that some of the newly created `<p></p>` and inserted in DOM are bit shifting or dynamically adjusting to the left side. You can check the result here: https://icelandico.github.io/nato-alphabet-decoder/ . 
How to avoid this unattractive effect?

Here's the portion of code responsible for this effect:

`<div class="item result">
</div>`

```
 .result,
 .full-codes-list {
     width: auto;
     white-space: nowrap;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
 }

.result p,
.full-codes-list tr {
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #05386b;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    text-align: left;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0}
    to { opacity: 1}
}


  function putInDom() {
    let newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.innerHTML = result[counter];
    resultDiv.appendChild(newParagraph);
    counter < result.length - 1 ? counter ++ : clearInterval(wordInsert)
 }

function decode() {
  inputValue = searchValue.value;
  inputValue = inputValue.toUpperCase().split("").filter(character => 
  character.match(/[\S]/));
  result = (inputValue.map(letter => letter in alphabet ? alphabet[letter] :
  letter));
}
```

The `alphabet` variable is an object that stores a letter and relating code for it.

Comment: Didn't understand the problem. On what condition are you facing the problem?

Comment: Try to type any word in the searchbar. You'll see that appearing result would be 'floating' to the left and shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS, the CSS is available in your stylesheet. I have just added `text-align: center`

```
.result p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

OR

```
.result, .full-codes-list {
    width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That works but my goal was to align all words to the left to have first letter one under another.

Comment: then you need to fixed the container width.

Comment: Well that works better! But! How to center all paragraphs in div and align them to the left at the same time? Do I have to wrap paragraphs in another div?

Comment: Align center will not work here as the elements are taking the max width at runtime whenever a new element is injected into the DOM. Otherwise, you can hide the container initially and then inject all the element in that div and later show them one by one with animations.

Comment: That seems to be good solution for this. Trying to implement it now.

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it has given you a sufficient idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured out that it's only the case if there first appears a short word and then a longer. Why? Well because its creating a div with the smallest word to the width of that word. Then comes a longer word and the width increases. So the first word shifts to the left a bit. When you do it the other way around: first the long word than a shorter word it's not shifting.

So maybe it would help to set a certain width, like 10%;

See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried this earlier, the problem with fixed width is that all content (all <p> are not centered to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I think using CSS Flexbox (detailed [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) would make it perfectly stable.

Essentially, you just need to add this to the **end** of your existing CSS:

```
.result {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0;
}

.result p {
    flex: 1 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's an example (the icons don't work):

```js
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.menu--clear--button');
const searchButton = document.querySelector('.menu--search--button');
const searchValue = document.querySelector('.menu--value');
const resultDiv = document.querySelector('.result');
const fullCodeListTable = document.querySelector('.table-codes');
const contentDivs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content'));
const menuButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button'));
let inputValue;
let result;
let counter = 0;
let wordInsert;

// Input Buttons

clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearInput);
searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearResult();
  decode();
  intervalAppend();
});

searchValue.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  enterSearch(event.key)
});

// Menu Buttons

menuButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let clickedIndex = menuButtons.indexOf(e.target);
    clearResult();
    hideAndShowNextButton(e.target);
    clearDivs();
    showProperDiv(clickedIndex);
  })
});

function decode() {
  inputValue = searchValue.value;
  inputValue = inputValue.toUpperCase().split("").filter(character => character.match(/[\S]/));
  result = (inputValue.map(letter => letter in alphabet ? alphabet[letter] : letter));
}

function putInDom() {
  let newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  newParagraph.innerHTML = result[counter];
  resultDiv.appendChild(newParagraph);
  counter < result.length - 1 ? counter ++ : clearInterval(wordInsert)
}

function clearInput() {
  searchValue.value = '';
}

function enterSearch(event) {
  if (event === 'Enter') {
    clearResult();
    decode();
    intervalAppend();
  }
}

function intervalAppend() {
  wordInsert = setInterval(putInDom, 500)
}

function clearResult() {
  counter = 0;
  resultDiv.innerHTML = '';
  result = [];
}

function generateList() {
  clearContent();
  let newTableRowHeader = document.createElement('tr');
  let newTableHeader1 = document.createElement('th');
  let newTableHeader2 = document.createElement('th');
  newTableHeader1.innerHTML = 'Symbol';
  newTableHeader2.innerHTML = 'Code';
  newTableRowHeader.appendChild(newTableHeader1);
  newTableRowHeader.appendChild(newTableHeader2);
  fullCodeListTable.appendChild(newTableRowHeader);
  for (key in alphabet) {
    let newCodeRow = document.createElement('tr');
    let newRowDataChar = document.createElement('td');
    let newRowDataCode = document.createElement('td');
    newRowDataChar.innerHTML = key;
    newRowDataCode.innerHTML = alphabet[key];
    newCodeRow.appendChild(newRowDataChar);
    newCodeRow.appendChild(newRowDataCode);
    fullCodeListTable.appendChild(newCodeRow)
  }
}

function clearContent() {
  while (fullCodeListTable.firstChild) {
    fullCodeListTable.removeChild(fullCodeListTable.firstChild);
  }
}

function hideAndShowNextButton(element) {
  menuButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    if (button.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      button.classList.remove('hidden')
    }
    element.classList.add('hidden');
  })
}

function clearDivs() {
  contentDivs.forEach(function(div) {
    div.classList.add('hidden')
  })
}

function showProperDiv(index) {
  contentDivs[index].classList.remove('hidden')
}

const alphabet = {
  "A": "Alfa",
  "B": "Bravo",
  "C": "Charlie",
  "D": "Delta",
  "E": "Echo",
  "F": "Foxtrot",
  "G": "Golf",
  "H": "Hotel",
  "I": "India",
  "J": "Juliett",
  "K": "Kilo",
  "L": "Lima",
  "M": "Mike",
  "N": "November",
  "O": "Oscar",
  "P": "Papa",
  "Q": "Quebec",
  "R": "Romeo",
  "S": "Sierra",
  "T": "Tango",
  "U": "Uniform",
  "V": "Victor",
  "W": "Whiskey",
  "X": "Xray",
  "Y": "Yankee",
  "Z": "Zulu",
  1: "One",
  2: "Two",
  3: "Three",
  4: "Four (Fower)",
  5: "Five",
  6: "Six",
  7: "Seven",
  8: "Eight",
  9: "Nine (Niner)",
  0: "Zero"
};

generateList();
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Swis721 LtEx BT", sans-serif;
}

html {
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #5cdb95;
    color: #05386b;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: unset;
}

.wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top-banner {
    margin: 1% auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: "Swis721 LtEx BT", sans-serif;
}

.menu {
    min-height: 125px;
    background: #379683;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu--buttons {
    margin: 2% auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 75%;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    margin: 1%;
    background: #05386b;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    letter-spacing: 5px; ;
    font-size: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.menu-searchbar:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.input {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    background: #379683;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    border: 3px solid #05386b;
    border-left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.about {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5%;
}

.about p {
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.about a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #379683;
}

.menu--value {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 3px solid #05386b;
    background: #5cdb95;
    color: #05386b;
    font-weight: 500;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #05386b;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button:focus, input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #5cdb95 inset;
}

.active-content {
    margin: 2% auto;
}

.result,
.full-codes-list {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.result {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0;
}

.result p,
.full-codes-list tr {
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #05386b;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    text-align: left;
}

.result p {
    flex: 1 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

td:first-child {
    text-align: center;
    padding:1%;
}

th {
    padding: 2% 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #379683;
}

th:first-child {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.result p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0}
    to { opacity: 1}
}

.result p:first-letter {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #05386b;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #379683;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.footer-item {
    width: 50%;
}

.footer-header {
    color: #05386b;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2rem;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.footer-icons {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.footer-icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #05386b;
    width: 15%;
}

a span:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
    .button {
        max-width: 35%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .footer-header {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" style="">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item top-banner">
    <h1>Nato Phonetic Alphabet</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item menu">
    <div class="menu--buttons">
      <button type="button" class="button button--search-bar hidden">Search</button>

      <button type="button" class="button button--full-list">Full codes list</button>

      <button type="button" class="button button--about">About</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="active-content">
    <div class="content item menu-searchbar">
        <input class="input menu--value" type="text" placeholder="Type Your word" name="name" required="">

        <button class="input menu--search--button" type="button"><span class="icon fas fa-search"></span></button>

        <button class="input menu--clear--button" type="button"><span class="icon fas fa-backspace"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="content full-codes-list hidden">
      <table class="table-codes"><tr><th>Symbol</th><th>Code</th></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>Zero</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>One</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Two</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Four (Fower)</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Five</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>Six</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>Seven</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>Eight</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>Nine (Niner)</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>Alfa</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>Bravo</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>Charlie</td></tr><tr><td>D</td><td>Delta</td></tr><tr><td>E</td><td>Echo</td></tr><tr><td>F</td><td>Foxtrot</td></tr><tr><td>G</td><td>Golf</td></tr><tr><td>H</td><td>Hotel</td></tr><tr><td>I</td><td>India</td></tr><tr><td>J</td><td>Juliett</td></tr><tr><td>K</td><td>Kilo</td></tr><tr><td>L</td><td>Lima</td></tr><tr><td>M</td><td>Mike</td></tr><tr><td>N</td><td>November</td></tr><tr><td>O</td><td>Oscar</td></tr><tr><td>P</td><td>Papa</td></tr><tr><td>Q</td><td>Quebec</td></tr><tr><td>R</td><td>Romeo</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>Sierra</td></tr><tr><td>T</td><td>Tango</td></tr><tr><td>U</td><td>Uniform</td></tr><tr><td>V</td><td>Victor</td></tr><tr><td>W</td><td>Whiskey</td></tr><tr><td>X</td><td>Xray</td></tr><tr><td>Y</td><td>Yankee</td></tr><tr><td>Z</td><td>Zulu</td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <div class="content about hidden">
    <p>
      For more information about NATO Phonetic Alphabet visist this
      <a href="https://www.osric.com/chris/phonetic.html" target="_blank">site</a>
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item result"></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer-item footer-header">By Michal M.</div>
  <div class="footer-item footer-icons">
    <a class="footer-icon" href="https://twitter.com/cartohistory" target="_blank"><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span></a>
    <a class="footer-icon" href="https://linkedin.com/in/micha%C5%82-muszy%C5%84ski-819352118" target="_blank"><span class="fab fa-linkedin"></span></a>
    <a class="footer-icon" href="https://icelandico.carbonmade.com/" target="_blank"><span class="far fa-map"></span></a>
    <a class="footer-icon" href="https://github.com/icelandico" target="_blank"><span class="fab fa-github-square"></span></a>
    
    <address><a class="footer-icon" href="mailto:michal.muszynski@pm.me" target="_blank"><span class="far fa-envelope"></span></a></address>
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't work because the results have to be aligned to the left to have first letter one under another, not centered.